# Remove duplicate from an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hashmap

I want to output an array of hashes with the `name` being unique to all hashes. How would I go about doing this using ruby?

This is my input:

```
input = [{:name => "Kutty", :score => 2, :some_key => 'value', ...},
         {:name => "Kutty", :score => 4, :some_key => 'value', ...},
         {:name => "Baba", :score => 5, :some_key => 'value', ...}]
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
  output = [{:name => "Kutty", :score => 4, :some_key => 'value', ...},
            {:name => "Baba", :score => 5, :some_key => 'value', ...}]
```

Comment: I basically don't want duplicate hash entry in the array!. And i want it based more score.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, your given output is wrong. Kutty's highest score is 4.

Comment: yes mark.. Anyway I got solution.. Just an conditional operator is need to change. Thanks for the find.. I ll update my ques.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To just remove duplicates based on :name, simply try;

```
output = input.uniq { |x| x[:name] }
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/CTa4J).

**Edit:** Since you added a sorting requirement in the comments, here's how to select the entry with the highest score for every name if you're using Rails, I see you already got an answer for "standard" Ruby above;

```
output = input.group_by { |x| x[:name] }
              .map {|x,y|y.max_by {|x|x[:score]}}
```

A little explanation may be in order; the first line `groups` the entries by name so that each name gets its own array of entries. The second line goes through the groups, name by name, and `maps` each name group to the entry with the highest score.

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/Ip4at).

Answer (score 4):

```
input = [{:name => "Kutty", :score => 2, :some_key => 'value'},{:name => "Kutty", :score => 4, :some_key => 'value'},{:name => "Baba", :score => 5, :some_key => 'value'}]
p input.uniq { |e| e[:name] }
```

The above solution works for ruby > 1.9, for older versions of ruby you could use something along these lines:

```
input = [{:name => "Kutty", :score => 2, :some_key => 'value'},{:name => "Kutty", :score => 4, :some_key => 'value'},{:name => "Baba", :score => 5, :some_key => 'value'}]
unames = []
new_input = input.delete_if { |e|
  if unames.include?(e[:name])
    true
  else
    unames << e[:name]
    false
  end
}
p new_input
```

Comment: It is not working.. I 'm getting the same result.. I 'm using ruby 1.8.7. Any way it helps me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution..

```
input = [{:name => "Kutty", :score => 2, :some_key => 'value'},
         {:name => "Kutty", :score => 4, :some_key => 'value'},
         {:name => "Baba", :score => 5, :some_key => 'value'}]


a = []
output = []
input.collect do |i|
  input.delete(i) if !a.include?(i[:name])
  output << i if !a.include?(i[:name])
  a << i[:name] if !a.include?(i[:name])
end


output = [{:some_key=>"value", :name=>"Kutty", :score=>2}, 
          {:some_key=>"value", :name=>"Baba", :score=>5}]
```

**UPDATED**

```
output = {}
input.each do |e|
  ref = output[e[:name]]
  if ref && ref[:score] > e[:score]
    #nothing
  else
    output[e[:name]] = e
  end
end
```

check output:

```
puts output.values
```

Comment: Thanks Sangeeth.. your solution is working fine but i'm waitng for more answers. since i need a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
input.uniq{|hash| hash[:name]}
```